Why does VerifyFortranC fail when building LAPACK with cmake on windows?
I work on a project and LAPACK/LAPACKE (and OpenBlas) is needed as dependency for SAF.
For LAPACK the Fortran/C interface is tested for compatibility. I get this Warning first:
-- Verifying Fortran/C Compiler Compatibility
CMake Warning (dev) at D:/Programs/JetBrains/CLion_2023.1.2/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FortranCInterface.cmake:309 (message):
  No FortranCInterface mangling known for VerifyFortran

Then this Error:
CMake Error at D:/Programs/JetBrains/CLion_2023.1.2/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FortranCInterface.cmake:400 (message):
  The Fortran compiler:

    C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/gfortran.exe

  and the C compiler:

    D:/Programs/JetBrains/CLion_2023.1.2/bin/mingw/bin/gcc.exe

  failed to compile a simple test project using both languages.  The output
  was:

    Change Dir: D:/Coding/Studium/BA_SAF_PA/SAF_copy_building/dev_example/cmake-build-default-mingw/CMakeFiles/FortranCInterface/VerifyC
    
    Run Build Command(s):D:/Programs/JetBrains/CLion_2023.1.2/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe VerifyFortranC && [1/1] Linking C executable VerifyFortranC.exe
    FAILED: VerifyFortranC.exe 
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Programs\JetBrains\CLion_2023.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/main.c.obj CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/VerifyC.c.obj -o VerifyFortranC.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libVerifyFortranC.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0   -LC:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc   -LC:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib   -LC:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib libVerifyFortran.a  -lgfortran  -lgcc_s  -lquadmath  -lm  -lgcc_s  -lgcc_s  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
    D:\Programs\JetBrains\CLion_2023.1.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: D:/Programs/JetBrains/CLion_2023.1.2/bin/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `__p__commode'
    D:\Programs\JetBrains\CLion_2023.1.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/VerifyFortranC.dir/main.c.obj:main.c:(.text.startup+0xf): undefined reference to `VerifyFortran'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake-build-default-mingw/_deps/lapack-src/LAPACKE/include/CMakeLists.txt:17 (FortranCInterface_VERIFY)


ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
D:\Programs\JetBrains\CLion_2023.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --regenerate-during-build -SD:\Coding\Studium\BA_SAF_PA\SAF_copy_building\dev_example -BD:\Coding\Studium\BA_SAF_PA\SAF_copy_building\dev_example\cmake-build-default-mingw

The compiler both have the same version:
GNU Fortran (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

The CMake file (with out the other dependencies to keep it shorter):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(dev_example VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(FetchContent)

FETCHCONTENT_DECLARE(
        lapack
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/Reference-lapack/lapack
        GIT_TAG        master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(lapack)
FetchContent_GetProperties(lapack)
if(NOT lapack_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(lapack)
endif()

add_executable(dev_example WIN32
        main.cpp
        )

target_link_libraries(dev_example
        lapack
        lapacke
        openblas
        )

Do I have to specify a mangling to make it work?
